why defatting of a tissue for protein extraction has to be done at 75oC with 1:4 (w/v) ratio of sample to isopropanol? does it denature protein?
I am extracting clam muscle for proteins which include defatting with 4x volume of isopropanol at 75oC for 90 minutes. is this the optimum conditions or do i have to do any modification to recover the protein?

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

If it were a crime book, the title would say, who is the murderer, near all paper sheets would be empty and the
detective would ignore  crime circumstances and forensic methodology.
